# React native npm package not work with export styles

Tags: react-native, npm-package

I create a NPM package for a react-native project.

```
--- MyComponent.tsx
--- /styles/MyComponent.style.ts
```

I separated the file component from the style file.

But white screen and impossible to operate the application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised. `StyleSheet` not work in NPM package. We need to declare directly in `styke` props file.